# Bring Thingspeak data JSON into Highcharts Multiline Example

Tags: json, highcharts, series, multiline

I want to create a multiline chart with my own data from thingspeak cloud.
The demo I have tried to modify is: https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

This part of the code:

```
     `const promises = names.map(name => new Promise(resolve => {
            (async () => {
                const data = await fetch(
                   ** 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/' +
                    'samples/data/' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json'**
                )
                    .then(response => response.json());
                resolve({ name, data });
            })();
        }));
`
```

must be modified to:

`https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/**channel_id**/feed.json` 
(with the right id copied to a browser status line it loads my data field 1 to field 8)

Else:

- I am aware, that the names of my fields must then correspond to the field names in:
  const names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'];
- I have to insert in the header:

So far I don't get it run.

Question 1: I have tried to search various examples and hints, but no success. How to provide the right working URL in that await fetch part? Most example show CSV, but I am having Thingspeak cloud. And usually this works by $get.JSON .. and such an URL: https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/**channel_id**/feed.json

Question 2: is it possible to show in the example fiddle two columns and one line? or is that not possible and it will be always same serie type?

Thank you very much for you hints, Manfred

Comment: The first link doesn't work. What you wrote regarding this API is not entirely understandable. Additionally, it is difficult to help in this area because it is a paid solution. I would suggest writing to thingspeak cloud support. I can only help with the second question. You can achieve this by setting the series type: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dtcgo3vh/

Comment: Thank you very much Michal. I apolgize. The link really does not work, but it referred to Highstock demo, mulitline. The code the get data into the chart is copied above in the window written under "This part of the code ..." My API api Thingspeak call has not included my personal channel id for public reasons. It should serve as example. Q2 is related to that demochart. https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/compare